# How can I create a Javascript/Jquery algorithmic function that will calculate on load--and re-draw during mousedrag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, frontend

I've begun development on a web app, and I'm just now tackling some of the first front-end obstacles. I'll give you some details about the front-end first, just to make sure the context of my question is clear.

**Below is a diagram, showing the different elements relevant to the question.*
[image]

Each `Node` is draggable. If you would , please take a quick look at http://labs.inversepenguin.com to view a test `canvas` with one `node` active.

**Diagram notes:**

`Node 2` 's position in Figure 2 has changed from it's location in Figure 1, resulting in an extra `link` being displayed. My goal is to have the newly created `link` appear the instant `node2` has been dragged the necessary distance... as opposed to say, after the user drops `node2`.

---

> *"How can I create a Javascript/Jquery algorithmic function that will calculate on load--and re-draw during mousedrag?"*

---

The desired function would consist of:

- An algorithm to analyze the distance
  between `nodes` to determine how many
  `links` should be displayed.
- Create/destroy `links` based upon results.
- To position each resulting `link` appropriately; centered and evenly
  spaced.

**I'm confident in my geometry and math abilities to handle the execution of the function--but I'm not sure how to make the function "listen" and "re-draw" during mousedrag.**

---

I was maybe thinking maybe having the function call itself at it's end, after an `if` checking to see if the user is "still dragging," but I'm new to programming and don't have a firm grasp on what's practical.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: are you using canvas or html/dom elements? (ps. lovely diagram!)

Comment: @Tom Tu - Dom elements. The `links` will be carefully positioned divs with background images most likely; HTML5's canvas has no relation--sorry for the confusion.

Comment: By wary of event handling on mousemove/drag as it's CPU intensive.

Comment: @Raynos - Would it be worth it to use a setTimeout() in conjunction with the "listener function" or something? What other options do I have for a "live re-draw" of the `link` count/positioning, besides abandoning this model or using flash?

Comment: @Raynos - For example, could I run a looping function after "dragstart" fires, and until "dragstop" fires? Is that circumventing the CPU issues of mousemove/drag, or just re-packaging it?

Comment: @Julian something like registering on drag and using a frameskip would work. I.e. only redraw every 5th/10th/50th drag event depending on your own mix of smoothness vs speed

Comment: @Raynos - Do I create a loop (i++) and run the function when i = 10, 20, 30, etc... ? Is that what you mean by frame skip?

Comment: @Julian `global var frameskip = 0; $(..).bind("drag", function() { if (frameskip++ % 10) // do stuff });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) for your dragging, you could define the `start`, `drag`, or `stop` events to do the appropriate work.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dragstart", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});

$( ".selector" ).bind( "drag", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});

$( ".selector" ).bind( "dragstop", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

The challenge I see is that each node will have to know what is connected to it.  I have done this before by creating my own attributes.  Using your 2 node solution above:

```
<div id="node1" child="node2" />
<div id="node2" parent="node1" />
```

If you have nodes linked to multiple other nodes, you could just do something like

```
<div id="node1" children="node2;node3;node4" />
```

with a delimited list of children.  Then retrieving this information for your processing would be as simple as `var children = $(this).attr('children').split(';');` and that will get you an array of the children's id's.  You can also get the position of the element and the children, calculate the distance, and modify your links.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your input... some nuggets in this one :P So would `$( ".selector" ).bind( "drag", function(event, ui) {` automatically repeat the function while "dragging," or would I need to employ something like a self-calling function? The "live re-calculating and re-draw" is what's I'm foggy on.

Comment: The documentation says *This event is triggered when the mouse is moved during the dragging.*  It is repeatedly called.  You can see a demonstration at http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events

Comment: Thanks for your input--you definitely gave me some good ideas... especially about multiple nodes, because there definitely will be :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use jQuery anyway, I would recommend to use the [draggable-functionality of jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). It easily enables you to make elements draggable and also allows you to bind a custom function to a `drag`-event. This function is then called whenever the user moves his mouse while dragging the element, so it could be used to update the "links".

Of course, you can also bind the same function to the load-event of the page to create the initial "links".

Comment: I am using JqueryUI Draggables for the `node` elements, and the Mapbox Jquery plugin for the `canvas`. I'm going to look into the `drag` event though--maybe that could help with the "still dragging" aspect.